# What does VertexContract do?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

From the documentation,

> `VertexContract[g, {v1, v2, ...}]` contracts a collection of vertices `v1`, `v2`, ...  into a single vertex of the graph `g`.

Let's try it:

```
VertexContract[CycleGraph[6], {3,4}] // EdgeList

(* {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 3, 5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 3} *)
```

Vertices `3` and `4` were contracted into a single vertex now named `3`.  Effectively we have a cycle on vertices `1`, `2`, `3`, `5`, `6`. So far so good.

> `VertexContract[g, {{v1, v2, ...}, ...}]` contracts several collections of vertices.

I am not getting this one.  I expected

```
VertexContract[CycleGraph[6], {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}]
```

to contract the pairs `{1,2}`, `{3,4}` and `{5,6}`, each, and get this graph:

```
{1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 5, 5 <-> 1}
```

I.e. a cycle on `1`, `3`, `5`.

Instead I get a graph with a single vertex and no edges.  Why?  What does this command actually do?

---

I can do

```
Fold[VertexContract[#1, #2] &, g, {{v1, v2, ...}, ...}]
```

to achieve the result I expected, but it's pretty slow when there's a lot to contract.

Comment: True, and surprising, this is not what one expects. Maybe the contraction of {1,2} lead to the new node three, contraction with {3,4} and after that {5,6} contracts to a single node. But this is not what I (one) would expect.

Comment: @mgamer I need this functionality, and I need it to work fast, so I [exposed](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/commit/a7461e374cb2b058616923ca538117107a51aae8) the corresponding function in [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM).  It will be in the next release.

Comment: I now had this problem, too. Making an example of the construction of the Petersen-Graph of tuples {I,j} with empty intersection to {k,l}. I did a `ToString /@ VertexList[graph]`... and similar for EdgeList. This than worked as expected (but up to now I did not do timing analysis - the PetersenGraph is not too large ;-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if there is no difference between passing a list of lists and the same vertices in a single list.  To check this, I try a variety of random cases

```
test := Module[{n, m, p, q, g, list, g1, g2},
  n = 100;
  m = 300;
  p = RandomInteger[{2, 5}];
  q = RandomInteger[{2, 5}];
  g = RandomGraph[{n, m}];
  list = RandomChoice[VertexList[g], {p, q}];
  g1 = VertexContract[g, list];
  g2 = VertexContract[g, Flatten[list]];
  g1 === g2]
```

I have never seen the test fail

```
And @@ Table[test, 1000]
(* True *)
```

Obviously, this is not absolute proof, but if there were some subtle difference one might expect the documentation to make it a little clearer!